# Xcode - Replace content in '< >' of String

Tags: ios, string, replace, tags, expression

I search this question but didn't find anything useful.

For example, I have this string:

```
NSString *text = @"Siguiendo la estela del <a class="colorbox" href="http://www.applesfera.com/apple/apple-presenta-un-nuevo-anuncio-del-iphone-y-vuelve-por-su-derroteros">anuncio Photos Every Day en el que la compañía de la manzana nos mostraba situaciones cotidianas para hacer hincapié en que cada día se hacen más fotos con el iPhone que con cualquier otra cámara"
```

And I want to eliminate, ALL content in '< >' tag, ('<''>' inclusive), so the result that I want, will be:

```
NSString *text = @"Siguiendo la estela del anuncio Photos Every Day en el que la compañía de la manzana nos mostraba situaciones cotidianas para hacer hincapié en que cada día se hacen más fotos con el iPhone que con cualquier otra cámara"
```

I see it's possible with regular expression, but I don't know how.
Need guidance on what on what i could do here.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493153/search-for-a-string-between-two-known-strings) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002360/get-string-between-two-other-strings-in-objc) with slight modification will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942245/nsregularexpression-for-stripping-html-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886998 .I think this is what you are looking for. If you want to resue it in many place implement as specified in that post.
Else  simply use like this

```
NSRange r;
NSString *s = @"my<remove>output";
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple substitution of a string, you can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` like this:

```
NSString* result = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<.*?>"
                                                   withString: @""
                                                      options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                        range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
```